# Ember js RC1 - mixin methods/properties not applied

Tags: ember.js

In our current implementation on Ember (v1.0.0-pre.2) we have this:

```
var LoggingMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    LOGGING: false,

    log: function (message) {
        if (this.LOGGING) {
            Ember.Logger.log(logMessage);
        }
    }
});

var SomeNamespace = Ember.Namespace.create(LoggingMixin, {
});
```

This allowed us to call `SomeNamespace.log('message')`.  This does not seem to work for Ember.js RC1.  Javascript reports: `TypeError: SomeNamespace.log is not a function`.

Instead, what *does* seem to work in RC1 is this:

```
var SomeNamespace = Ember.Namespace.extend(LoggingMixin);
var someNamesapce = SomeNamespace.create();
```

Now calling `someNamespace.log('message')` *does* work.

So my question is whether the mixin creation/behaviour has changed in RC1 or am I doing missing something w.r.t. the original code.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a breaking change in *Ember 1.0.0-pre.3 (January 17, 2013)*:

- BREAKING CHANGE: `Ember.Object.create` behaves like `setProperties`. Use `createWithMixins` for the old behavior.